# Macbook Air: MD232LL/A or Z0ND0002Z?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm planning to buy a new high-end macbook air and found that there're different part numbers for the same product: MD232LL/A and Z0ND0002Z. What is the difference between these two? Is it just about the released country or do they have different specs actually?

I appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two model numbers don't seem to refer to the exact same configuration. Model MD232LL/A appears to reference to the base model (as noted in Apple's [MBA Model Identifier KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3255)). The KB also notes:

> If you have a custom configuration the Model Number and Configuration
>   in the table may not match. **Please use the Model Identifier to confirm
>   the model of MacBook Air for custom configurations**.

One example from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00746YD24) - the specs include:

> - 1.8 GHz Intel Core i5 Processor
> - 256 GB Flash Storage
> - 4 GB DDR3 RAM

In the page from [Decide.com](https://www.decide.com/p/laptops-apple-apple-z0nd0002z-13-3--33013099), the specs for model Z0ND0002Z include:

> - Core i7 2 GHz
> - 8 GB RAM
> - 512 GB HDD

It's probably that the Z0ND0002Z model is used by retailers that provide more customization, since Apple uses the MD232LL/A model in its online KB. The excerpt from the KB also supports this conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, JW8. I understand your point but I'm a little bit curious how multiple (unofficial) retailers use the same unauthorized model number Z0ND0002Z. My major concern is whether this model is an official customization or an uncertified illegal retrofit. I also wonder if there could be possibility (though small) of getting an unexpected product if I order this Z0ND0002Z model. Anyway your answer was very helpful. Thanks again! :)